# lpSolve package seems to give strange results

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve, convex-optimization

I am using the R "lpSolve" package [downloaded from Cran link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/index.html) and it seems to give strange answers. I wanted to make sure that it is not me messing up things (which is likely the case).

For example, the problem I am trying to solve is

```
maximize -3x-2y
s.t       5x -y <=  1
         -2x-2y <= -1
         -3x-2y <=  0
```

The settings I have in R:

```
> obj
   -3 -2
> cond
    5   -1
   -2   -2
   -3   -2
> dir
   "<=" "<=" "<="
> rhs
   1 -1  0
```

With these applied to the lp function in lp.solve

```
> lp(direction="max", objective.in=obj, const.mat=cond, const.dir=dir, const.rhs=rhs)$objval
```

This returns -1, however, I know the solution is 0 instead of -1.

I also tried set the objective to be "min" instead, and I get:

```
> lp(direction = "max", objective.in = obj, const.mat = cond, const.dir = dir, const.rhs = rhs)$objval
[1] -1
> lp(direction = "min", objective.in = obj, const.mat = cond, const.dir = dir, const.rhs = rhs)$objval
[1] 0
```

How is it possible that I get a bigger value when I try to minimize the objective? Does it have something to do with negative coefficient with x? I looked through the package manual and I didn't see any related requirements for the objective function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that `(x, y) = (-1, 1.5)` yields an objective value of 0, which from the constraints is clearly the maximum possible.

The thing that is holding you back from obtaining this is the following line in `?lp`:

> Note that every variable is assumed to be >= 0!

Under the assumption that every variable is non-negative, indeed -1 is the best you can do.

To solve your original problem, you could define non-negative decision variables `x+` and `x-` to represent the positive and negative parts of `x`, and do the same for `y`. Here is the resulting optimization model:

```
mod <- lp(direction = "max",
          objective.in = c(obj, -obj),
          const.mat = cbind(cond, -cond),
          const.dir = dir,
          const.rhs = rhs)
mod$objval
# [1] 0
mod$solution[1:2] - mod$solution[3:4]
# [1] -1.0  1.5
```

In all cases, the effect of the transformation used here is removing the non-negativity requirement of the variables and keeping everything else the same.

Lastly, the reason your minimization looked like it was giving you an objective value of 0 is that it's actually unbounded and didn't set the `objval` value in its response:

```
lp(direction = "min", objective.in = obj, const.mat = cond, const.dir = dir, const.rhs = rhs)
# Error: status 3
```